# WPF Custom Button's Command Binding doesn't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, custom-controls

I created a custom button that inherits the Button class. I added some dependency property that I need to let the user specify how the button will look like.

The button looks great and the dependency property also worked as I wished. But however, the Command property doesn't work no matter how I try.

Here's my sample:

```
public partial class CustomButton : Button
{
    ... //some dependency property
    public CustomButton()
    {
       ...//do some initialization
       //I tried checking the Command property over here but it seems like always to be NULL?!
    }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<Button x:Class="CustomButton"
        xmlns:.....>
   <Button.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="CustomButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" Height="22">
                    ......more things behind...
   </Style>
   </Button.Resources>
   <Button.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}">
   </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

I used it in my other windows control like this:

```
 <Controls:CustomButton Command="{Binding NewCommand}" ToolTip="AddNew"/>
```

The command always not being executed, why? Did I miss out anything? 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you use a normal button instead? Check the output window for binding errors

Comment: Yes Thomas, it works if i use normal button.

Comment: Please provide the full control template that you're applying via style.

Answer (score -1):

Guessing your template just makes it difficult to actually click on the button. As an experiment, try setting the background of the root `StackPanel` to solid `Red` rather than `Transparent` and see if that makes it easier to click.

Comment: hi, i tried that, it doesn't fix it. FYI, the problem seems to be related to the command binding. Because I can mouse over, I can click, and all the styles seems to be working. Just the command doesn't seems to be passing down from the parent template.